# Android Wear: Layout is not displaying properly in Emulator

Tags: java, android, android-layout, wear-os, android-wear-2.0

I'm developing an Android smart watch application. The initial screen appears fine. But, when I go to next screen, the upper part pops up with the name of project something like this. In the below image, Watch is the name of the project.

[image]

I want to see the entire screen instead of white space which contains project's name. Does anyone know how to solve it and why is it appearing?

My XML file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@color/black"
        android:weightSum="1"
        tools:ignore="UselessParent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/sign_up_top_bar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textview"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="@string/text"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:fontFamily="Century-Gothic.ttf" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageView1"
                android:layout_width="18dp"
                android:layout_height="19dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/text"
                android:src="@drawable/fingerprint" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <Button
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:background ="@drawable/roundedbutton"
            android:text="@string/button_text"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:drawablePadding="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:layout_height="75dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.34" />


    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout>
```

Comment: What theme are you using for your activity? You might need one with "NoTitleBar".

Comment: I'm using Theme.AppCompat.Light.

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25953614/round-android-wear-emulator-is-using-rect-layouts), there are many problems with inflating layouts that are caused by not correctly using `WatchViewStub`. One common issue is when you register a listener for watch insets so you can check if it is round or square inside your `onApplyWindowInsets` handler.

Additional reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28754782/android-wear-round-emulator-inflating-square-layout

Comment: Hi Abielita. I'm not using WatchViewStub. I'm using Boxinsetlayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question was simple. I figured out after one day. I changed my theme from **Theme.AppCompat.Light** to **Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar** in Manifest file. The program name bar disappeared.

Comment: I think its standard to use device default with android wear. No need to use appCompat. <style name="Theme.main" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">

Answer (score 1):

Use a [BoxInsetLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wear/widget/BoxInsetLayout.html) for your root layout:

> This class applies the required window insets depending on the screen
>   shape and lets you easily align views on the center or near the edges
>   of the screen.

And I would highly recommend you to read through this tutorial.

Edit 2:

You need to use:

```
android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout
```

not:

```
android.support.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout
```

and add to the mainContainer:

```
app:layout_box="all"
```

---

```
<android.support.wearable.view.BoxInsetLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

<LinearLayout
    app:layout_box="all"
    android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/black"
    android:weightSum="1"
    tools:ignore="UselessParent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">
```

Comment: I changed my layout to BoxInsetLayout. It still displays in the same way.

Comment: Show me your xml layout file

Comment: I forgot to tell you, to add this line. now it will work.

Comment: It still is displaying in same way even after adding that line :|

Comment: The first screen which is having login details, I have used the same layout. It works fine. I don't know why it is not working for second screen,

Comment: I edited the answer try it now and tell me if it works :D

Comment: There is an alternative if needed, but I think this will work now.

Comment: check if you added **app:layout_box="all"** to the linearLayout

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151846/discussion-between-obsthandler-and-sarvesh-kulkarni).

Comment: Yes. I copy-pasted what you have written in my layout directly.

Comment: The answer was simple. I changed my theme from Theme.AppCompat.Light to Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar in Manifest file. The program name bar disappeared

Comment: Thanks for all the help @Obsthandler